# Fire function only once if another has already been fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created two functions. To keep it simple lets take for an example the following:

I got functions firing different events for the same objects. You can activate them using your `keyboard arrows`

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (event.which == 39) open_second_layer();
});
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (event.which == 37) open_first_layer();
});
```

As soon as I have fired one function and press the same key again it fires the animation one more time (unnecessarily).

Because of that as soon as the function `open_second_layer` has been fired, it should not be able to be fired again, until `open_first_layer` is fired again. The same should be the case the other way round.

I found `.bind` and `.when` as possible solutions, but can't figure out how to use them the right way for that case. I appreciate every suggestions or keywords to google.

Comment: a bit more code would be useful.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use `.slideToggle()`?

Comment: Hey @PHPglue, yes, I am sure. `slide_first/second` stands for a number of different actions to take place, its not actually sliding a div to another!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a state variable and track when changes are made to it:

```
var state_changed = (function() {
    var current = null;

    return function(state) {
        if (state == current) {
            return false;
        }
        current = state;
        return true;
    };
}());

function open_first_layer()
{
    if (!state_changed(1)) {
        return;
    }
    // rest of code
}

function open_second_layer()
{
    if (!state_changed(2)) {
      return;
    }
    // rest of code
}

$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (event.which == 39) {
        open_second_layer();
    } else if (event.which == 37) {
        open_first_layer();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey @Jack, thanks for your response. I like the idea of your snippet. Depending on my jQuery skills I am not sure if I have inserted my code the right way. I have replaced `// rest of code` with my keyboard selector `$("body").keydown(function(e) {
        if (event.which == 39) open_second_layer();
    });` 

It does not work for me. Is there an error in implementing my own code? I appreciate any suggestions, best regards, Marian.

Comment: @MarianRick Yeah, that's not right ... I've updated my answer based on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Put the other function inside `slide_first`, like:

```
function slide_first(){
  // other code
  $('#activate_second').one('click', slide_second);
}
$('#activate_first').one('click', slide_first);
```

or use an Anonymous function to do the same:

```
$('#activate_first').one('click', function(){
  // slide_first code here
  $('#activate_second').one('click', function(){
    // slide_second code here
  });
});
```

Maybe your really want:

```
function recursiveSlider(){
  $('#activate_first').one('click', function(){
    // slide_first code here
    $('#activate_second').one('click', function(){
      // slide_second code here
      recursiveSlider();
    });
  });
}
recursiveSlider();
```

Comment: This doesn't work the other way around, i.e. "activate_second" followed by "activate_first".

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer! I have used your last snippet and adjusted it to my needs, but it does not seem to work. I think the concept is good and simple. Is there an mistake in adopting your snippet?

`// RecursiveSlider
function recursiveSlider(){
    $("body").one("keydown", function(){
        if (event.which == 39) open_second_layer();
        $("body").one("keydown", function(){
            if (event.which == 37) open_first_layer();
            recursiveSlider();
        });
    });
}
recursiveSlider();`

Comment: Here's the flaw with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/uh63rzbp/ - watch your console and notice that the events keep stacking up (they shouldn't!).  This is buggy code with a very bad memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

In your first click handler, you bind the second one.

In your second click handler, you bind the first one.

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jtmju8xs/)

```
<div id=activate-first>first</div>
<div id=activate-second style="display:none;">second</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    function slide_first(){
        $('#activate-first').show();
        $('#activate-second').hide();
        $('#activate-second').one('click', slide_first);
    };

    function slide_second(){
        $('#activate-first').hide();
        $('#activate-second').show();
        $('#activate-first').one('click', slide_second);
    };

    $('#activate-first').one('click', slide_second);
    $('#activate-second').one('click', slide_first);
});
```

Comment: Hey, i am sorry, because I did not provide enough information about the system I am using your answer does not work for me. I have updated my question. Thanks for your suggestion and effort, I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for delegation.  You have a single click event, and whenever the event happens, you determine what has been clicked, and you take action accordingly:

```
$(document.body).on("click", function(ev) {
    var $targ = $(ev.target);

    if ($targ.is('#button_1')) {
        // someone clicked #button_1
    }

    if ($targ.is('.page-2 *')) {
        // something inside of .page-2 was clicked!!
    }
});
```

UPDATE: now the OP has included more code, I'm not sure the issue is - there's no need to bind and unbind events...

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/uh63rzbp/1/

```
function open_first_layer() {
    $('#first_panel').addClass('active');
    $('#second_panel').removeClass('active');
}

function open_second_layer() {
    $('#first_panel').removeClass('active');
    $('#second_panel').addClass('active');
}

// one event === good
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (event.which == 39) open_second_layer();
    if (event.which == 37) open_first_layer();
});
```

... or if you're trying to build a slider, I suggest changing your naming convention:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/uh63rzbp/2/

```
var current_layer = 1,
    $all_layers = $('[id^="panel_"]'),
    total_layers = $all_layers.length;

function move_layer (dir) {
    current_layer += dir; 
    if (current_layer < 1) current_layer = total_layers;
    else if (current_layer > total_layers) current_layer = 1;

    $all_layers.removeClass('active');
    $('#panel_' + current_layer).addClass('active');
}

// one event === good
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (event.which == 39) move_layer(1);
    if (event.which == 37) move_layer(-1);
});

move_layer(0);
```

Comment: Oh my god downvoters.  Why the hate.  `$.one` is the most unmaintainable solution on this page.  I actually couldn't make a better case for event delegation.  Binding and unbinding events (eg. `$.one`) is memory leak hell...